# Asking patches in-radius with AND & OR conditions

Tags: netlogo

I'm trying to ask a subset of patches in a given radius to carry out an action. I was wondering if it is possible to call patches in-radius with both the AND and the OR controls? Example: I want to call patches with forest, *or* grass *or* patches with crop that are *also* certified, so something like this:

```
To identify-patches

   ask patches in-radius 5 with [land-cover = "forest" OR land-cover = "grass" OR land-cover = "crop" 
   AND certified? = "yes"

End
```

I've tried a couple of bracket combinations but none seemed to select the subset of patches I was looking for, it seemed that as soon as I used AND, this condition was applied to all patches. So, I'm wondering if y'all knew a way I can ask this subset with these conditions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So the certification only applies to grass and crops? If so, I think this is what you want:

```
to identify-patches
  ask patches in-radius 5 with [land-cover = "forest" or ((land-cover = "grass" or land-cover = "crop") and certified? = "yes")]
end
```